# "read more" link in mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I need a plugin for mootools like [this](http://www.reindel.com/truncate/#examples).

It's just a simple button which, when clicked, opens up a hidden portion of a div with an **animation**. When the page is loaded it closes to a point (truncating to some **x** characters) in the same div. If you take a look at the link, you'll understand...

But I need it for **mootools**, not jQuery. :(

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to look at is the [official Mootools plugin repository](http://mootools.net/forge/) but it doesn't look like there is a Mootools equivalent.

Converting the jQuery plugin to Mootools may not be that difficult, at least porting the minimal features you want to use.

Good luck.

---

**EDIT: see this [expander](http://mootools.kassens.net/expander/) experiment**